# The term for time spent understanding the code of a legacy application

Tags: c#, coding-style, agile

I'm having difficulty trying to remember the term describing the wasted time of trying to understand the code of a legacy application that has no documentation. I had thought the term was code rediscovery, but Google is telling me I'm misremembering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably referring to [Software/Code Archaeology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_archaeology) which is the process of studying badly/not documented legacy projects/code.

Comment: ... and now i think of Indiana Jones and Lara Croft, sitting at their laptops and hacking away... ^_^

Comment: Bang on, and a wiki article to boot :)